# Getting a uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Given any discrete random variable $X$, is it always possible to find a change of variables $Y = g(X)$ such that the new variable, $Y$, is uniformly distributed?

Comment: Let $X$ be constant and the probability space $[0, 1]$ with Lebesgue measure.

Comment: It's always impossible. There exists a value $a$ so that $P(X=a)>0$. Hence  $P(g(X)=g(a))>0$, so $g(X)$ is not uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want $Y$ to be a *continuous* uniformly distributed variable, then no, that is not possible. Since $X$ is discrete there will be some $x_0$ such that $P(X=x_0)$ is positive, but then $P(Y=g(x_0))$ will be positive too, and a uniform continuous distribution has probability $0$ on every singleton.

---

You can make $Y$ be a *discrete* uniform distribution, though you may have to let it be uniform over a single element. Suppose, for example that $X$ is $0$ with probability $\frac23$ and $1$ with probability $\frac 13$. Them your only hope of getting a "uniform" distribution is to let $g(0)=g(1)$.

Comment: I didn't understand the last part, "a uniform continuous distribution has probability 0 on every singleton". I was asking about a discrete uniform distribution, not a continuous one. Why did you bring that up?

Comment: @Tendero: Bacause I'm not a mind reader. You may have had a discrete uniform distribution in mind, but you didn't say so explicitly in the question.